# How to make the whole content of the screen scroll in ios objective-c app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIImageView` on my `ViewController`, I also placed a `CollectionView` below it in `storyboard`. I populate the `collectionView` and with data and when I run the app, only the `collectionview` section scrolls, while the image view remains static on the page even while scrolling through the list of `collectionView` items. I wan the whole screen content to scroll up when the top item of `collectionView` is reached. How do i do this in objective-c. If it will be with a scroll view, how do ii implement this?
Images below illustrate how it is on iPhone music app in the radio tab section, which contains banner and collection view below, when i scroll up the banner moves out of sight above, and the collection view appears and the remaining content. that's what i want, the banner shouldn't be static

[image: image of screen before scrolling up]

[image: Image of screen after i scroll up]

Comment: give screenshot of expected results

Comment: I just added some screen shots to illustrate what i want

Answer (score 0):

Have a `UIScrollView` as a parent for for image view and collection view. And your image view and collection view inside the scrollview. Now set `contentSize` property of the parent scrollview.

```
var size : CGSize
let height = imageView.frame.height + heightOfCollectionView // heightOfCollectionView is height calculated from total number of cells/sections present in collection view
size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width,height)  //assuming
scrollView.contentSize = size
```

Set this is `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of your view controller

Comment: can i have it in objective-c please

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the screenshots you can create a collectionview cell just to present that image view and put that cell at the top.